# What is wrong with the way I am trying to get data out of the Perl hash?

Tags: perl

This is probably an easy question but I can't figure it out.  I have a structure that is returned from a routine that, when I print with Data::Dumper, looks like

```
$VAR1 = {
  'date' => 'May 15, 2012',
  'value' => '0.20'
};
```

But I can't get the data out of it.  If I try `$data{value}` I get nothing.  I am not that familiar with Perl. Can anyone help me? What am I missing?

Comment: What you're missing is `use strict; use warnings;`. Always use that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `$VAR1` is a hash ref, not just a hash.  So you need to dereference the variable to get at the data:

```
$VAR1->{date}
$VAR1->{value}
```

This is Perl, so TMTOWTDI (There's More Than One Way To Do It):

```
$$VAR1{date}
$$VAR1{value}
```

However, the explicit `->` arrow operator is generally easier to understand; the operand on the left is a reference, and the bit on the right accesses it (`$hash->[0]` for an array ref; `$hash->{item}` for a hash ref).

You could use instead:

```
my %VAR2 = ('date' => 'May 15, 2012', 'value' => '0.20');
```

Now you can write:

```
$VAR2{date}
$VAR2{value}
```

(I could have used both `%VAR1` and `$VAR1`; they're distinct variables — but that's extra confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how your subroutine is written. I would guess that it's returning a *reference* to a hash, in which case your code should look something like this:

```
my $data = my_subroutine();
print $data->{value}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't honoring the TYPE of the variable. Perl supports hashes, denoted by the `%` sigil, and hash-references using `$`. The second are scalars, and have to be dereferenced to get to the data. Using perl's debugger:

```
DB<1> $VAR1 = { 'date' => 'May 15, 2012', 'value' => '0.20' };

DB<2> x $VAR1->{'date'}
0  'May 15, 2012'
DB<3> x $VAR1->{'value'}
0  0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/perl
$VAR1 = { 'date' => 'May 15, 2012', 'value' => '0.20' };
$date = $$VAR1{date};
$value = $$VAR1{value};
print "$date\n";
print "$value\n"
```

prints out:

```
May 15, 2012
0.20
```

The reason for this is $VAR1 is a reference to an anonymous hash.